# Listing AWS S3 bucket content from Springboot With Apache Camel

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, apache-camel

I have a sprintboot project running v2.5.4 which works fine.
I have access to S3 and im able to list the content of a bucket i have created. So i wanted to experiment with Apache Camel to try to just list the content of a bucket which should be pretty simple according to the examples. But i keep getting errors.

I added 2 dependencies to my build.gradle

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.camel.springboot', name: 'camel-core-starter', version: '3.13.0'
implementation group: 'org.apache.camel.springboot', name: 'camel-aws2-s3-starter', version: '3.13.0'
```

and then i simply created a SimpleRouteBuilder.java

```
@Component
```

public class SimpleRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("aws2-s3://bucketName?amazonS3Client=#createS3Client&operation=listObjects&accessKey=xxxAccessKeyxxx&secretKey=xxxSecretKeyxxx")
            .log("Received body: ");
}
```

And i keep getting this stacktrace

On my aws s3 client factory i have set the bean name

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class S3ClientBeanFactory {

    @Bean(name = "s3Client")
```

and this seems to work - when i change the name to something else i get
an error about this :

```
No bean could be found in the registry for:S3Client
```

But with the "s3client" set in the camel endpoint url i get this all the time

```
2021-12-13 12:23:25.036  INFO [,,] 28267 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.13.0 (camel-1) shutdown in 4ms (uptime:511ms)
2021-12-13 12:23:25.045  INFO [,,] 28267 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-12-13 12:23:25.069  INFO [,,] 28267 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-12-13 12:23:25.085 ERROR [,,] 28267 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route1 because of null
2021-12-13 12:23:25.036  INFO [,,] 28267 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.13.0 (camel-1) shutdown in 4ms (uptime:511ms)
2021-12-13 12:23:25.045  INFO [,,] 28267 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-12-13 12:23:25.069  INFO [,,] 28267 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-12-13 12:23:25.085 ERROR [,,] 28267 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route1 because of null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:123)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doWarmUpRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:306)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:189)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:147)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:3201)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2863)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2814)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringBootCamelContext.doStart(SpringBootCamelContext.java:43)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2510)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:246)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at dk.danskespil.scratchgames.ScratchgamesApplication.main(ScratchgamesApplication.java:22)
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: null, Extended Request ID: FknaUW6/yRkYvJry9d8oIWU2hC4aRk7z8ilAZZxlcDN4s+P4bAoyzWVriJxUYj2bCyzCFFMSGNY=)
```

Is this operation not possible or what am i missing to do such simple operation ?

Comment: If you want to invoke Amazon S3 from Java, why are you not using the official AWS SDK for Java?

Comment: @smac2020 That is a Camel endpoint-abstraction over the official SDK.

Comment: The spring boot project already works with AWS SDK and I just wanted to experiment with camel to see if it was easier to use when i need multiple similar integrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with Apache Camel component *aws2-s3://* which was caused by **insufficient rights** on AWS S3:

```
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, ...)
```

But I have to mention that **S3Client from Amazon SDK works well** for reading files with the same rights = the same account.

Explanation: I found that this *aws2-s3://* component requires making *headBucket* API call (and the others) which causes the error because of insufficient rights for making this api call.

Comment: Yes its the same result as i found out and commented below. I got a DevOps to change something on aws that made it work. Sorry that i dont know what he changed.

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't consider configuration beans to be special. It is possible that the route bean is created before the S3 client bean.

I'd try using the `@DependsOn({"s3ClientBeanFactory"})`-annotation on the route bean. More on it here: [Controlling Bean Creation Order with @DependsOn Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-depends-on)

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it didnt change anything

Comment: Looking at your question again you have the bean working fine... The problem you have is with authenticating: `Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: null, Extended Request ID: FknaUW6/yRkYvJry9d8oIWU2hC4aRk7z8ilAZZxlcDN4s+P4bAoyzWVriJxUYj2bCyzCFFMSGNY=)`

Comment: I just dont understand why the auth should fail. I use the same s3ClientBeanFactory to the original project and this works just fine. When i define the accessKey and secretKey in the 'from' part of the route, how does this work with defining the s3ClientBeanFactory which also needs a accessKey and secretKey ?

Comment: I tried the cli "aws s3 ls --profile xxxx and put the accessKey and secretKey in the .aws/credentials file - and it works fine with the same set of keys.

Comment: If you're still working on this, I'd try making sure it really is using the correct credentials. To me it just seems like the credentials being picked up are not the correct ones.

Comment: I did a few tests and it seems that im stuck with a call s3Client.headBucket() which camel is doing and which is not allowed. I tried this with the CLI and even though we can list files in the bucket and gave the user all rights, i still get 403 on headBucket(). 
So im not getting closer to a solution than this sofar

Comment: So i got it solved after all. As mentioned above it had to do with the rights of the aws/bucket. I had a devops help me which set the correct policies etc. He was lead on by this : https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/1338
Not sure how to resolve this issue

Comment: If you got everything working I think you could write an answer yourself and then mark this as solved.

Comment: I got it solved but it was a DevOps that solved it by changing something on the aws user side - and i dont know what it is

Comment: I see... If there's no way for you to find out, I guess you should just close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is too late but could be useful for others with the same problem.

You have to register the software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client in the camel registry. To pickup the aws credentials of the profile from the.aws folder you have to provide a ProfileCredentialsProvider, specififying the profile name, in case you don't have will be default, something like this worked for me.

```
    @Bean("S3Client")
public S3Client s3Client(CamelContext camelContext){
    //Depends on the profile name generated in .aws folder, in this case default
    ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.builder().build();
    S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder()
            .region(US_EAST_1)
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
    camelContext.getRegistry().bind("s3Client", s3Client);
    return s3Client;
}
```